# Setting Mac OSX 10.11 Volume Programatically using XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I need a way to change volume (and mute the volume) in osx 10.11

There was a way before 10.11 and that code was

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = {
            kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume,
            kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
            kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
        };

        AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData([self.class defaultOutputDeviceID],
                                            &propertyAddress,
                                            0,
                                            NULL,
                                            sizeof(Float32),
                                            &volume);
```

But this no longer works in 10.11

The other way I found was using applescript

```
NSAppleScript* asdown = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"output volume of (get volume settings)"];
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [asdown executeAndReturnError:nil];

        NSAppleScript* asdown2 = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"set volume output volume (%@ - 6.25)", [result stringValue]]];
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *result2 = [asdown2 executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

But I dont like to use this way because when the screen it turned off, about 30 seconds after it no longer responds to commands

So is there a way for me to be able to change the volume of the mac running 10.11 without using applescript?